# RecyclerView not vertically scrollable in PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragment, preferencefragment

I have a fragment of preferences (SettingsFragment) and I have an activity (SettingsActivity) that uses this fragment.

I don't know why my list of preferences in the fragment is not scrollable. I know that PreferenceFragmentCompat uses his RecyclerView by default.

This is my code.

**SettingsFragment.java**

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
    }
}
```

**preferences.xml**

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
    ...>

    <androidx.preference.EditTextPreference
        android:inputType="number"
        android:title="Event"
        android:key="event"/>

    <!-- Other Preferences... -->

</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);


        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment preferenceFragment = new SettingsFragment();

            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, preferenceFragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

}
```

**activity_settings.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    ...
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        ...>
    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Have you constrained the `fragment_container` in the XML file.

Comment: @NatarajKR yes, I didn't show it here for semplicity

Comment: Please share the full content of activity_settings.xml. The problem is most probably there.